# How to Impersonate Nifi Logged in LDAP user to hdfs

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

I have a scenario where i hope someone somewhere might have tried implementing it.

1. Apache Nifi integrated with LDAP.
2. I get logged in using userid created in LDAP.
3. my hdfs is integrated with LDAP.
4. how do you think can i impersonate my nifi logged in user to access HDFS data.

Reason for implementing this approach is.
1. I am trying to avoid using kerberos which i know is supported by apache nifi.
2. I want to keep centralized logging system so that i dont need to worry and maintain multiple such repo.
3. Why LDAP, as i am using LDAP client to manage users and roles.
4. I am already using LDAP to autheticate users to access hdfs data for someother apache application thus sticking to LDAP will let me avoiding making changes to those applications.

Your ideas and inputs are much appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't do this.

The longer answer... Processors don't execute as the web users that are logged in to NiFi. When a user is in the UI they change the state of a processor to "running", the processor then runs according to its run schedule. At the time it is executing there is no knowledge of the user that was in the UI that set it to "running". The only identity it runs as is the kerberos identity specified in the processor, or if that is not being used then it will end up being the operating system user that launched the NiFi process.

Comment: Hello Bryan, thank you for your response. one more query if thats ok with you . Does nifi supports spoofying a hardcoded userid in core-site.xml to hdfs, why spoofying is as to access hdfs data we need to import core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml into the nifi listHDFS processor for example. what if we try adding spoofying property in core-site.xml for a specific userid and then does it work, i mean have this been tried before ?

Comment: the link here is for windows 
   https://mapr.com/docs/60/AdvancedInstallation/SettingUptheClient-config-mapr-client.html   , but anything similar have ever been tried and tested before ?, to emphasize, i am running nifi inside kubernetes cluster